# $\mbox{Im }A\oplus \ker A^t = V$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $A:V\to V$ be an endomorphism of a finite dimensional linear space. It's easy to see that $\mbox{Im }A\cap \ker A^t = 0$. Because if $w = Av\in \ker A^t$, then $0 = \langle A^tAv,v\rangle = \langle Av,Av\rangle = \|Av\|$, this implies $Av = w = 0$. Also we observe that $\dim \mbox{Im }A =\mbox{rk }A=\mbox{rk }A^t = \dim \mbox{Im }A^t$, thus $\dim \mbox{Im }A+\dim \ker A^t = \dim \mbox{Im }A^t+\dim \ker A^t = \dim V$. Therefore  $\mbox{Im }A\oplus \ker A^t = V$.

What's a natural way to see this decomposition of $V$? Given $v\in V$, how do we compute $v = Aw+u$ where $u\in \ker A^t$?

Comment: Is $A$ non-singular? otherwise, $\text{rk} A^t \leq \text{rk} A.$

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani It follows from row rank = column rank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key word is *[least square linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression#Least-squares_estimation_and_related_techniques)*. $Aw$ is the orthogonal projection of $v$ to the column space of $A$.

To your second question: if $v=Aw+u$, then $A^t v = A^t A w$ and $w=(A^t A)^{-1} A^t v$ (if $A^t A$ is regular).

$Aw$ is in some sense the best approximation of $v$ in the space generated by the columns of $A$. The "error" $u$ is "perpendicular" (if you use a standard scalar product in $\mathbb{R}^n$) to all columns of $A$; $Aw$ is the vector that minimizes the sum of squares of coordinates of the difference $v-Aw$. (This procedure works well and is commonly used in statistics especially if $A$ has more rows than columns; the columns are usually independent in this more general case.)

I assume in my answer that you ask about matrices; for a general vector space and an endomorphism, it is not clear what is $A^t$ (unless you have a scalar product).